# Задержка элемента меню на CSS с помощью jQuery (или может есть другой способ)?

Tags: jquery, css

Есть менюшка, сделанная c помощью CSS, где при наведении курсора на элемент появляются другие элементы меню. Собственно сама проблема: нужно чтобы при отводе курсора с активного элемента, была некоторая задержка для появившихся элементов (ну чтобы успеть навести курсор на них). Ниже код css:

```
#ololomenu {
    background: url("../img_menu/background.png") no-repeat;
    height: 350px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
}
#ololomenu
li {
    display: block;
    height: 72px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 72px;
}
#ololomenu
li.paint {
    background: url("../img_menu/paint.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: 120px;
    top: 14px;
}
#ololomenu 
li.past {
    background: url("../img_menu/past.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: 210px;
    top: 50px;
}
#ololomenu
li.child {
    background: url("../img_menu/child.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: 45px;
    top: 50px;
}
#ololomenu
li.brush {
    background: url("../img_menu/brush.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: 240px;
    top: 125px;
}
#ololomenu 
li.hobby {
    background: url("../img_menu/hobby.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: 15px;
    top: 125px;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby zag {
    background: url("../img_menu/zag.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: -45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -76px;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby deko {
    background: url("../img_menu/deko.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: -75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby bat {
    background: url("../img_menu/bat.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: -45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 76px;
}
#ololomenu 
li.paper {
    background: url("../img_menu/paper.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: 210px;
    top: 200px;
}
#ololomenu
li.work {
    background: url("../img_menu/work.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: 55px;
    top: 190px;
}
#ololomenu 
li.varn {
    background: url("../img_menu/varn.png") no-repeat center center;
    left: 130px;
    top: 235px;
}
#ololomenu 
li a b {
    display: none;
}
#ololomenu 
li a {
    display: block;
    height: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 72px;
}
#ololomenu 
li a:hover {
    background: url("../img_menu/circle.png");
    font-family: georgia, serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#ololomenu
li a:hover b {
    background: url("../img_menu/bktext.png");
    color: #63352c;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}
#ololomenu
li a:hover b span {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#ololomenu
li.paint a:hover b {
    left: -5px;
    top: 110px;
}
#ololomenu 
li.past a:hover b {
    left: -94px;
    top: 74px;
}
#ololomenu
li.child a:hover b {
    left: 70px;
    top: 74px;
}
#ololomenu 
li.brush a:hover b {
    left: -127px;
    top: -2px;
}
#ololomenu 
li.work a:hover b {
    left: 60px;
    top: -87px;
}
#ololomenu
li.paper a:hover b {
    left: -94px;
    top: -77px;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby a:hover b {
    left: 99px;
    top: -7px;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby hob_hide {
    display: none;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby:hover hob_hide {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    display: block;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby zag a:hover b {
    left: 145px;
    top: 75px;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby deko a:hover b {
    left: 174px;
    top: 0px;
}
#ololomenu
li.hobby bat a:hover b {
    left: 145px;
    top: -76px;
}
#ololomenu
li.varn a:hover b {
    left: -17px;
    top: -111px;
}
```

Просмотреть ее можно здесь: http://moskatelnaya-lavka.ru/test.html

Comment: Боюсь, что когда такие элементы делаются чисто на css, то задержку им не сделать. Нужно вмешательство js.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ololomenu ul').delay(150).slideUp(150);
```

Comment: ну типа того :)