# Задержка hover в css

Tags: css

Этот вопрос рассматривался здесь: [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/28667/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1)

Можно ли это реализовать на чистом css?

```
navHover = function() {
    var lis = document.getElementById("navmenu-v").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
            lis[i].onmouseover=function() {
                    this.className+=" iehover";
            }
            lis[i].onmouseout=function() {
                setTimeout(1000);
                    this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" iehover\\b"), "");
            }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", navHover);
```

Comment: Как я понял, transition не получиться повесить на ul>li 2го уровня, если родительский элемент стоит без transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Ftransition-delay).

**UPD:**

По поводу hover - проще сделать

```
jQuery('селектор').hover(
    function () { "A" },
    function () { "B" }
);
```

где A - обработчик hover, а B - обратный.

Comment: вот-же http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/uv3CN/ просто делайте delay 0; в :hover элементе...

Comment: @Радик Камалов, обновил ответ

Comment: Радик, сделайте fiddle с демонстрацией, трудно вот так сказать что там у вас происходит.

Comment: oooenergy.ru сейчас все без js
На display:none ставлю задержку, не задерживается.

Comment: display: none; не может быть "транзишном" используйте visibility: visible | hidden; и opacity: 1 | 0. ах да и тразишн проще написать одной строчкой transition: all 0.5s 2s; вот пример посмотрите: http://jsfiddle.net/hyy46/

Comment: c visibility работает, только почему то при потери элементом фокуса текст становится жирным, при наведении опять нормальным. Это transition так делает?